# Gulp and Webpack. Проблема с Async/Await

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp, async-await

Настроил Gulp и подключил к нему Webpack с помощью WebpackStream, когда пытаюсь скомпилировать JS файл с Async функцией появляется такая ошибка:

[image]

Без Async функции с Promise работает всё ок. Пытался пофиксить проблему явным добавлением entry файла в настройку webpack: ['@babel/polyfill', 'index.js'], ошибка не пропала.
Кто знает как решить? Настройка Gulp для JS:

```
function javascript() {
  return src(path.source.js)
    .pipe(webpackStream({
        mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
        output: {
            filename: "index.js"
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js)$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            '@babel/preset-env',
                        ],
                        plugins: [
                            [
                                "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", 
                                { "regenerator": true }
                            ]                               
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }))
    .pipe(dest(path.dest.js));
}
```

Comment: может быть функция и не является асинхронной, раз для нее ключевое слово await это неожиданность

Comment: Угу, сразу не увидел, там вложенность из 3х функций, и я указал в родительской async вместо дочерней, где await код..мелочь, но полтора часа на решение проблемы потратил:(
Спасибо за ответ)